# Office 365 MyFiles API - How to get the direct children in the root of the One Drive folder

Tags: api, office365

I'm trying to work with the new summer release of the [Office 365 API tool for Visual Studio 2013 (update 3)](http://blogs.office.com/2014/08/05/office-365-api-tool-visual-studio-2013-summer-update/). It works fine except one problem I've encountered which can be called also a missing functionality.

I found no reasonable way to retrieve the direct children of the root folder from my One Drive for business Document Library using the newly added SharePointClient library.

The API call of `SharePointClient.Files` will retrieve all the files and folders from the whole document library including sub-folders. So in order to get only the direct children I have to page through all the documents and folders and analyze their URL. This is not acceptable for my application scenario. For a sub-folder I can get the direct children like this: `SharePointClient.Files["<folder_id>"].ToFolder().Children` This is what I need but it can't be applied to the root folder.

I've tried to use the REST API directly and similarly the request GET ../_api/files will retrieve all files and folders in the default document library and I found no simple way to list only the direct children of the root. Also there is no convenient way to get the path or GUID of the default document library which the `SharePointClient.Files` automatically uses. 
Parsing the result XMLs of the REST API calls I may get the GUID of the default document library, that will let me use a different REST API to list files and folders separately for the root folder, but these calls results in a different XML schema from that used by SharePointClient. This means that to get only the direct children of the root I would have to re-implement the whole SharePointClient library.

If anybody has some good advice I'll be very thankful.

Comment: This issue was resolved in the latest relase of Office 365 API

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue - hopefully this will be remedied before the release version of the api tools. Here is what I've done to get only the root folder content:

```
[Create your spClient = SharePointClient]
var allFiles = await spClient.Files.ExecuteAsync();
var rootFiles = allFiles.CurrentPage.Where(i => !i.Id.Contains("/"));
```

You lose the IPagedCollection wrapper and you may need to get more than the 'CurrentPage' to see all files but this is the best workaround I've found. I'm then able to you the 'ToFolder()' method you mentioned above to list content of sub-folders.

Comment: you wouldn't happen to know how to get folder object by id ``await spClient.Files.GetById("folder_id").ToFolder().ExecuteAsync()``?